# Нужно ли в данном случае обособлять уточняющие обстоятельства?

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется следующее предложение:

> На прошлой неделе, в условиях зарождающейся оттепели, администрация США,
> по просьбе Москвы, начала военные переговоры о растущей российской
> поддержке сирийского режима.

Почему-то кажется, что первое обособление (*в условиях зарождающейся оттепели*) точно верное, а вот насчёт второго (*по просьбе Москвы*) есть сомнения.

Comment: Думаю этот вопрос надо задавать здесь https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Уточняющее обособленное обстоятельство - это выделяемое запятыми слово или сло­восочетание, которое отвечает на вопросы

ГДЕ ИМЕННО? КОГДА ИМЕННО? ОТКУДА ИМЕННО? КАК ИМЕННО?

и конкретизируют место, время или образ действия, о котором го­ворится в предложении.

На прошлой неделе в условиях зарождающейся оттепели администрация США по просьбе Москвы начала военные переговоры о растущей российской поддержке сирийского режима.

Когда? На прошлой неделе (обстоятельство времени)Когда именно? Можно ли ответить
"в условиях зарождающейся оттепели"?
Нет, и это очевидно.
А для "по просьбе Москвы" где вообще пара?

На прошлой неделе, во вторник, к нам приехали родители.